# AOV functioning different when using date versus a factor

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, anova

I'm running a simple ANOVA but when `Year` is a factor, the p-value doesn't show up. If I code `Year` as a numeric, the p-value shows up. I really want `Year` to be a factor instead of a continuous variable like a date.

```
dat <- structure(list(Year = structure(1:26, levels = c("1994", "1995", 
"1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", 
"2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", 
"2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2021"
), class = "factor"), no = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 14, 28, 0, 
2, 2, 6, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 0, 4, 3, 0, 0), yes = c(3L, 
5L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 16L, 30L, 19L, 23L, 2L, 40L, 16L, 23L, 11L, 2L, 
5L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 12L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 10L, 6L, 5L), percentage = c(75, 
83.3333333333333, 100, 50, 80, 84.2105263157895, 88.2352941176471, 
57.5757575757576, 45.0980392156863, 100, 95.2380952380952, 88.8888888888889, 
79.3103448275862, 91.6666666666667, 100, 83.3333333333333, 100, 
100, 100, 85.7142857142857, 58.3333333333333, 100, 66.6666666666667, 
76.9230769230769, 100, 100), total = c(4, 6, 2, 2, 10, 19, 34, 
33, 51, 2, 42, 18, 29, 12, 2, 6, 9, 1, 2, 14, 12, 5, 12, 13, 
6, 5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -26L))
```

The data set above is with Year as a factor. Here is my output:

```
summary(aov(percentage ~ Year, data = dat)) # not significant
#            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq
#Year        25   7030   281.2
```

Any ideas would help!

Comment: Also, you should model the output as binomial (number of successes out of total). You lose lots of information by looking at the frequencies. Learning about generalized linear models will be worth it.

Comment: @Zheyuan Li since this is biological data, it's important to treat each Year as individualized data so we figured a factor would be the best way

Comment: @Zheyuan Li I agree with your point about the time. It's a numerical issue. But even if they fix the numerical issue they are left with a statistical issue: the linear model is not a good choice for count data. Esp. since the totals vary quite a bit from year to year.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi The sample data indicates they have the actual counts. So there is no need to work with the frequencies.

Comment: @dipetkov would it be okay to run a glm model (poisson) on the number of "yes"'s and if Year is significant, then I can assume that Year is affecting the number of "yes"'s?

Comment: Looking at the plot that @ZheyuanLi helpfully did for us suggests that time in fact doesn't have an effect on the probability of yes, at least not a strong effect. (It does on the totals though, there is an uptick between 2000 and 2008.) Anyway, you have count data, so it would be better to use a model for count data.

Comment: @Cassidy I suggest you accept my answer, and move on to https://stats.stackexchange.com/ with my analysis results.

Answer (score 2):

> Since this is biological data, it's important to treat each year as individualized data so we figured a factor would be the best way.

```
head(dat)
#  Year no yes percentage total
#1 1994  1   3   75.00000     4
#2 1995  1   5   83.33333     6
#3 1996  0   2  100.00000     2
#4 1997  1   1   50.00000     2
#5 1998  2   8   80.00000    10
#6 1999  3  16   84.21053    19
```

There are plenty of issues here. I will talk about:

- linear model `percentage ~ Year` with `lm`/`aov`;
- logistic regression `cbind(yes, no) ~ Year` with `glm`.

#### What's wrong with using `lm`/`aov`

Statistically speaking, it is certainly not a good idea to model your manually calculated percentage (of "yes") using a linear regression. But there is an additional problem here: **you only have one observation per year.** It is certainly not reasonable to treat `Year` as a factor. In that way, you have as many regression coefficients as data, so that you are going to get a perfect fit with all residuals being 0. As a result, all test statistics and p-values will be `NA` or `NaN`.

```
lmfit <- aov(percentage ~ Year, data = dat)

## use `summary.lm()` for aov() fit to show coefficient table
summary.lm(fit)
#Call:
#aov(formula = percentage ~ Year, data = dat)
#
#Residuals:
#ALL 26 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!  ## dang!!!
#
#Coefficients:
#            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#(Intercept)   75.000        NaN     NaN      NaN
#Year1995       8.333        NaN     NaN      NaN
#Year1996      25.000        NaN     NaN      NaN
#Year1997     -25.000        NaN     NaN      NaN
#Year1998       5.000        NaN     NaN      NaN
#Year1999       9.211        NaN     NaN      NaN
#... trimmed; all NaN ...
#
#Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom
#Multiple R-squared:      1,    Adjusted R-squared:    NaN 
#F-statistic:   NaN on 25 and 0 DF,  p-value: NA

anova(lmfit)
#Analysis of Variance Table
#
#Response: percentage
#          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
#Year      25 7029.5  281.18     NaN    NaN
#Residuals  0    0.0     NaN               
#Warning message:
#In anova.lm(lmfit) :
#  ANOVA F-tests on an essentially perfect fit are unreliable  ## dang!!!
```

#### Switching to logistic regression with `glm`

In principle, we want a logistic regression below.

```
glmfit1 <- glm(cbind(yes, no) ~ Year, family = binomial(), data = dat)
```

However, there is still only one observation per `Year`, so you still get a perfect fit. In this case, the deviance residuals are all 0.

```
anova(glmfit1, test = "Chisq")
#Analysis of Deviance Table
#
#Model: binomial, link: logit
#
#Response: cbind(yes, no)
#
#Terms added sequentially (first to last)
#
#
#     Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev Pr(>Chi)    
#NULL                    25     70.107             
#Year 25   70.107         0      0.000 3.71e-06 ***
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I am not sure whether the p-value is valid here, given that we have 0 residual degree of freedom (i.e., a perfect fit).

One workaround (or maybe a cheating), is to transform your data to binary format.

```
Year_no <- with(dat, rep(Year, no))
Year_yes <- with(dat, rep(Year, yes))
fctr <- rep(c("no", "yes"), c(length(Year_no), length(Year_yes)))
fctr <- factor(fctr, levels = c("no", "yes"))
Year <- c(Year_no, Year_yes)
cheat <- data.frame(fctr = fctr, Year = Year)
rm(Year_no, Year_yes, fctr, Year)
head(cheat)
#  fctr Year
#1   no 1994
#2   no 1995
#3   no 1997
#4   no 1998
#5   no 1998
#6   no 1999
```

In this format, the sample size rises to 351, allowing you to treat `Year` as a factor without ending up with a perfect fit.

```
glmfit2 <- glm(fctr ~ Year, family = binomial(), data = cheat)
```

I thought these two specification of `glm` should give the same fit, but actually, they don't.

```
all.equal(glmfit1$coef, glmfit2$coef)
#[1] "Mean relative difference: 0.3250444"
```

Note that both model fitting have converged.

```
glmfit1$converged
#[1] TRUE

glmfit2$converged
#[1] TRUE
```

So I think this is really weird (could make a good question on https://stats.stackexchange.com/). But anyway, here is the ANOVA table.

```
anova(glmfit2, test = "Chisq")
#Analysis of Deviance Table
#
#Model: binomial, link: logit
#
#Response: fctr
#
#Terms added sequentially (first to last)
#
#
#     Df Deviance Resid. Df Resid. Dev Pr(>Chi)    
#NULL                   350     376.80             
#Year 25   70.107       325     306.69 3.71e-06 ***
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

In this case, the residual degree of freedom is 325. I tend to trust this result.

#### Closing Remark

This is what I can help on Stack Overflow. The next step for you should be seeking interpretation of these two logistic regression on https://stats.stackexchange.com/. Please share me with the question link, after you post the question there.

Comment: Thank you for expanding your answer to discuss the counts aspect. Actually, you did way more work than necessary, I think. Sometimes the data can't answer the question the OP wants to ask and it's reasonable to point out weaknesses.