# R Logistic Regression using summary table

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression, summary

Can I run multiple logistic regression in R using data not from whole database, but only using summarized values?
In other words, can I still run the logistic regression and build a model only when I have a table like this:

| Age Group | No outcome | Outcome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| female, 18-39 | 130 | 9 |
| female, 40-59 | 156 | 22 |
| female, 60 and older | 165 | 18: |
| male, 18-39 | 234 | 44 |
| male, 40-59 | 156 | 34 |
| male, 60 and older | 90 | 5 |

Comment: Yes `glm(cbind(\`No outcome\`, \`Outcome\`) ~ \`Age  Group\`, family = binomial)` (note that the outcome is now a 2 column result). You should however rename your columns to not include spaces, for ease of implementation (eg avoid needing the "`\``" for your columns)

Comment: @Oliver Isn't this problematic? 6 data for 4 coefficients?

Comment: That is a misunderstanding Zheyuan Li. Here we actually have 130 + 9 + 156 + 22 + 165 + 18 + 234 + 44+ 156 + 34 + 90 + 5 = 1063 observations (eg all outcomes). Hence there is no problem. You could expand each result to a single "Success/Not success" row and get that number of rows.

Comment: @Oliver But this is how `glm()` and `summary()` counts degree of freedom... I am indeed confusing about this.

Comment: I'd suggest a re-read of `generalized linear models` from 1986. 

Answer (score 0):

Adding to my comment: You can do this by using the definiton of comparing 2 columns described in `?glm`.

```
data <- data.frame(AgeGroup = c('female, 18-39', 'female, 40-59', 'female, 60 and older', 'male, 18-39', 'male, 40-59', 'male, 60- and older'),
           NoOutcome = c(130, 156, 165, 234, 156, 90),
           Outcome = c(9, 22, 18, 44, 34, 5))
fit <- glm(cbind(Outcome, NoOutcome) ~ AgeGroup, data = data, family = binomial)
```

This is equivalent to expanding each group to individual rows and doing a binary regression:

```
data_long <- do.call(rbind, lapply(split(data, data$AgeGroup), 
       \(data)data.frame(AgeGroup = data[, 1], outcome = rep(c(0, 1), c(data[,2], data[,3])))))
fit_long <- glm(outcome ~ AgeGroup, family = binomial, data = data_long)
summary(fit_long)
summary(fit) # identical
```

Comment: should be `cbind(Outcome, NoOutcome)`. The 1st column is success.

Comment: If we assume that we are interested in the "outcome" (seems logical indeed) i agree.

Comment: For good measure I've added the expanded version. Note while the df changes the p-values remain identical.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72840390/4891738?

Comment: Of course. THe basic misconception here, is that you are concluding that any binary or logistic regression with a single factor is invalid (as it can be written as "single observation logistic regression models"). The null-deviance being zero is indeed something odd, not seen in most cases, but the general consequence as such is that *one* approximation (the F test) will be invalid. This is actually also noted in the warning for `anova.glm(fit, test = 'F')` where it states that F test is not appropriate for binomial tests.